# How to call UseEndpoints() and MapGraphQL() for HotChocolate on Azure Function isolated/out-of-process?

Tags: c#, graphql, azure-functions, hotchocolate

I follow this repo https://github.com/chandsalam1108/GraphQLAzFunctionNet5 and https://chillicream.com/docs/hotchocolate/server/endpoints#mapgraphql

How do I call `MapGraphQL()`? I only have access to `IHost`:

```
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            var host = new HostBuilder()
                .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
                .ConfigureServices(s =>
                {
                    s.AddTransient<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();
                    s.AddSingleton<GraphQLAzureFunctionsExecutorProxyV12>();
                    s.AddGraphQLServer()
                    .AddQueryType<Query>()
                    .AddFiltering()
                    .AddSorting();

                }).Build();

            host.Run();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi @Motoko, any look? I have the same question!

Comment: No, I gave up and move on to not using this

Comment: I did not find either a single implementation that works with multiple schemas but I finally understood how it works, I am working on a solution, and I am very close to it.

Answer (score 0):

As version 13 preview of HotChocolate there is no support for schemas. So instead you can use this very compatible lib:

```bash
dotnet add package Markind.HotChocolate.AzureFunctions.IsolatedProcess
```

Then setup the schema name as you normally would do in `AddGraphQLServer("schemaName")`:

```cs
    using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

    var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
    .ConfigureServices(s =>{
        s.AddGraphQLServer("persons") // schema 1
        .AddQueryType<Query>();

        s.AddGraphQLServer("persons2") // schema 2 , etc.
        .AddQueryType<Query2>();
    })
    .AddGraphQLFunctions()// Add support for Azure FunctionS
    .Build();

    host.Run();
```

Then in your function use IMultiSchemaRequestExecutor

```cs
    private readonly IMultiSchemaRequestExecutor _executor;

    public GraphQLFunction(IMultiSchemaRequestExecutor executor)
    {
        _executor = executor;
    }

    [Function("GraphQLHttpFunction")]
    public Task<HttpResponseData> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = "persons/{**slug}")]
        HttpRequestData request)
        => _executor.ExecuteAsync(request, "persons");
```

> Notice last line has the schemaName:**"persons"**. Add another function to use  another schemaName.

If you switch to use Azure Function in-process, instead you can use this [equivalent](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Markind.HotChocolate.AzureFunctions).

Answer (score 0):

The latest stable version of [HotChocolate (version 13.0.5)](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HotChocolate/13.0.5) has out of the box support for Isolated Process Azure functions in .Net 6.0 and above. You need to install the latest version of their templates by running the following command from your terminal:

```
dotnet new -i HotChocolate.Templates::13.0.5
```

Once that is done, you can create a new project using the `HotChocolate GraphQL Function Isolated` template. This will automatically bootstrap your Azure Isolated Process function application to use GraphQL.

Check out this video for more detailed info about how to do this: [Serverless GraphQL with Hot Chocolate and Azure Functions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TTbyHeGDSIk)

Answer (score -1):

Ihost is used to build headless services and is used on a console application.

While using `MapGraphQL()` on an endpoint will help get and post requests.

Ihost is used to create host on which the app will run.

refer this [article](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/using-generic-host-in-dotnet-core-console-based-microservices) by STEVE GORDON